# Delete Query in web2py not working

Tags: python, web2py

This is the function for deleting a record from database.

```
def pro_del():
    d = request.get_vars.d
    db(db.products.product_id == d).delete()
    session.flash = "Product Deleted"
    redirect(URL('default','index'))
    #return locals()
```

The id is successfully getting passed to the function by get_vars(means d is getting its value). I checked it by returning locals.
The redirection is also working fine. Its also flashing the message.
 
Just the query is not working. The record is not getting deleted from the database.
Note:'d' is alphanumeric here

Comment: Have you enabled record versioning on this table?

Comment: No, I hadn't. So that was the problem.
But I don't get it. Enabling Record versioning just creates an archived db for the modifications done. So how this feature being disabled is restricting me from deleting a record.
Also, can we enable record versioning for individual tables ?

Comment: No, enabling record version does not enable you to delete records. It's the opposite -- with record versioning, instead of records being deleted, they are marked as inactive and excluded from query results. So, that's not your problem at all. Maybe try doing `int(d)`.

Comment: Actually it is getting deleted from the database after I enabled versioning. Now that tuple is removed from table also. Also, int(d) won't work because d is alphanumeric.

Comment: To be more precise, record versioning leaves records in tact if the table contains an is_active field (in which case, is_active is simply set to False and inactive records are filtered out of all queries). Versioned tables are often set up by adding `auth.signature` to the table, which includes the is_active field. If your versioned table includes an is_active field, then the records are not being deleted, just filtered out of queries. Otherwise, versioning should have no impact on whether delete is working or not.

Comment: I suggest you post an app exhibiting the behavior you describe on the Google Group so it can be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From web2py's DAL documentation:

> No create, drop, insert, truncate, delete, or update operation is actually committed until web2py issues the commit command. In models, views and controllers, web2py does this for you, but in modules you are required to do the commit.

Have you tried `db.commit()` after your `.delete()` ?